# How to preserve order of factor levels in R

Tags: categorical-data, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I have an unbalanced longitudinal data for glucose levels of some patients coming to a hospital.  My data looks like `id, date, glucose_level`. As I want to find the average glucose level by year in the hospital, I introduced another field `year` which is the year extracted from `date`. Now this is my model

`lmer( glucose_level ~ as.factor(year) + (1 | id))`

My question is how do I preserve the order of visit by the patient (or measurement taken by date ) in the model. i.e. for a given patient the model should pick the older dated measurements first before the later measurements.

Comment: Use ordered factor data type, check `?as.ordered`.

Answer (score 5):

By deafult, factor levels are ordered alphabetically in R.

```
fac <- as.factor(letters[1:3])
fac
# [1] a b c
# Levels: a b c
```

Here, `a` is the reference level as it is the first one.

There are two main ways to change the ordering.

- **Change the reference level**

  If you want to change the reference level, you can use `relevel`:

  ```
  fac2 <- relevel(fac, ref = "b")
  fac2
  # [1] a b c
  # Levels: b a c
  ```

  As you can see, `b` is the new reference level.
- **Set a certain order of levels**

  If you want to order the levels in a more complex way, you can use `factor`:

  ```
  fac3 <- factor(fac, levels = c("b", "c", "a"))
  fac3
  # [1] a b c
  # Levels: b c a
  ```

  With the `levels` parameter, you can set a certain order, Here, the order of levels is `b`, `c`, `a`. Again, `b` is the reference level.

Note that both approaches affect the order of levels only. The order of the actual values does not change.